# Is Flash Player 25 update (adobe-flashplugin) being late?

Tags: flash

I installed it through Ubuntu Software (Center) and I still haven't received the update (but I received previous updates). Is just a release time issue (like for Firefox for Ubuntu Canonical which is a bit delayed from the official Mozilla release)?
I have Ubuntu 16.10 (64-bit).

[I think it's different from Ubuntu software question ([Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283)) because this software is not maintained by Ubuntu community, but by Adobe itself]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player 25 is still in Beta. If you are in a hurry, you can obtain it [here](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html). [Beta software](https://techterms.com/definition/beta_software) is software that is still undergoing testing and hasn't been officially released. Personally I wouldn't expect anything from the repositories until after beta testing is complete. You can obtain the notes regarding Air and FP 25 [here.](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air25_flashplayer25_releasenotes.pdf)

Comment: No, I'm not in a hurry. I just wanted to know :-)

Comment: Flash version 25.0.0.127 [has been released](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/). Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the latest update of the `adobe-flashplugin` package is [stuck in -proposed](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin) for some reason.

*Edit:* Released now.